# Updating XML file with TransformerFactory adds empty lines between nodes

Tags: java, xml

I have the following method to update node values in XML file

```
static public void updateRepositoryValue(String fileName, String xpath, String value){
    try {
        String rootPath = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();
        String path = rootPath + "/src/main/resources/repository/" + fileName + ".xml";
        DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = b.parse(new File(path));

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        Node updatedNode = (Node) xPath.compile(xpath).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
        updatedNode.setTextContent(value);

        Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        tf.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(new File(path));
        tf.transform(domSource, sr);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Functionally it works.
The problem is that after each node update this code adds an empty lines between every file content lines (nodes).
Currently I use the code above to update the `secret` node value, but I don't think it matters what value do I update.
So from this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<general>
    <environment>staging</environment>
    <tenantNameDev>automationdev</tenantNameDev>
    <tenantName>automation5</tenantName>
    <tenantNameProd>automation3</tenantNameProd>
    <userName>automation5@yahoo.com</userName>
    <userNameDev>automationdev@yahoo.com</userNameDev>
    <incompleteDetailsNotification>Some of the details are incomplete or invalid</incompleteDetailsNotification>
    <ui>
        <multiValueAtt>Gender</multiValueAtt>
        <incompleteDetailsNotification>Some of the details are incomplete or invalid</incompleteDetailsNotification>
    </ui>
    <api>
        <ownerIdAnn>3052cb88-a5a6-40db-af95-e1225ecf45fe</ownerIdAnn>
        <schemaIdAnn>f60566b1-be2b-40b1-9663-a7bb52ba2d3f</schemaIdAnn>
        <ownerId>e3bd1480-09b5-4268-9126-6962238e9a1e</ownerId>
        <schemaId>fd2941ad-276e-42b7-88fb-5054e8acdc8c</schemaId>
        <ownerIdProd>5218f707-96de-4d4c-92c6-ebedd9ccbdbf</ownerIdProd>
        <schemaIdProd>f50f2ac3-8e38-4733-adac-4817e3c58643</schemaIdProd>
        <envClientId>PYJYF7XU017OGFH5RJ8Q</envClientId>
        <secret>6MmE3bELLzO29r1ToG7LoVspWqanNJNGZCP0tG0N</secret>
        <workspaceId>e3bd1480-09b5-4268-9126-6962238e9a1e</workspaceId>
        <partnerId>b0f95322-a898-4af1-8fc1-9a8951d0c13a</partnerId>
        <email>kukussfds@mailinator.com </email>
        <alternativeWorkspaceId>81e15977-070a-4e68-8808-e2e6bb134f25</alternativeWorkspaceId>
        <alternativeEnvClientId>PQSWUCNXVRL1LALUJBRJ</alternativeEnvClientId>
        <alternativeSecret>VYpdpQ81n6p7i5C8FL2ni1RVOrHlD34ESxI1FW8U</alternativeSecret>
        <serverDeployDelay>3500</serverDeployDelay>
    </api>
</general>
```

After 4 calling the method above I receive this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<general>




    <environment>staging</environment>




    <tenantNameDev>automationdev</tenantNameDev>




    <tenantName>automation5</tenantName>




    <tenantNameProd>automation3</tenantNameProd>




    <userName>automation5@yahoo.com</userName>




    <userNameDev>automationdev@yahoo.com</userNameDev>




    <incompleteDetailsNotification>Some of the details are incomplete or 
invalid</incompleteDetailsNotification>




    <ui>




        <multiValueAtt>Gender</multiValueAtt>




        <incompleteDetailsNotification>Some of the details are incomplete or invalid</incompleteDetailsNotification>




    </ui>




    <api>




        <ownerIdAnn>3052cb88-a5a6-40db-af95-e1225ecf45fe</ownerIdAnn>




        <schemaIdAnn>f60566b1-be2b-40b1-9663-a7bb52ba2d3f</schemaIdAnn>




        <ownerId>e3bd1480-09b5-4268-9126-6962238e9a1e</ownerId>




        <schemaId>fd2941ad-276e-42b7-88fb-5054e8acdc8c</schemaId>




        <ownerIdProd>5218f707-96de-4d4c-92c6-ebedd9ccbdbf</ownerIdProd>




        <schemaIdProd>f50f2ac3-8e38-4733-adac-4817e3c58643</schemaIdProd>




        <envClientId>PYJYF7XU017OGFH5RJ8Q</envClientId>




        <secret>6MmE3bELLzO29r1ToG7LoVspWqanNJNGZCP0tG0N</secret>




        <workspaceId>e3bd1480-09b5-4268-9126-6962238e9a1e</workspaceId>




        <partnerId>b0f95322-a898-4af1-8fc1-9a8951d0c13a</partnerId>




        <email>kukussfds@mailinator.com </email>




        <alternativeWorkspaceId>81e15977-070a-4e68-8808-e2e6bb134f25</alternativeWorkspaceId>



        <alternativeEnvClientId>PQSWUCNXVRL1LALUJBRJ</alternativeEnvClientId>




        <alternativeSecret>VYpdpQ81n6p7i5C8FL2ni1RVOrHlD34ESxI1FW8U</alternativeSecret>




        <serverDeployDelay>3500</serverDeployDelay>




    </api>




</general>
```

How can I prevent that?

Comment: I wonder if it's picking up or adding a new line character when it does the parse?

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for such tasks. Please edit your question and add the following (1) Input XML, (2) logic what needs to be done, and (3) Output XML.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Thank you for your response. Could you please show me a sample code using XSLT instead of TransformerFactory performing the similar action? I'm actually not familiar both with TransformerFactory and XSLT. As about additional details here: I think I detailed what I need and what happens. I need to update some node value in the XML file. After each call of the method, it adds a blank line between every file lines. I can paste here a whole XML file after removing the discrete data, but I'm not sure this will give more information. It's just an XML file with 1-2 depth levels

Comment: @Prophet, Sure, but first add ##1-3 from my previous comment to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown your source XML or your stylesheet - options like `xsl:strip-space` and `xsl:output indent="yes"` make a big difference.

My guess would be that you are copying all of the whitespace text nodes from the source document, and only some of the element nodes.

Comment: I have updated the file content etc according to Yitzhak's request. Let me know if you need any more details

Comment: I missed that this was the JAXP identity transformer you were using rather than an XSLT stylesheet ("TransformerFactory" tends to mean XSLT to me). I'd start by cutting out the indent="yes" serialisation option.

Comment: This is absolutely strange, but it helped! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I expect it's using a rather crude indentation algorithm where it always adds whitespace before an element without considering whether there is already enough whitespace there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a conceptual example for XSLT.

The XSLT itself is somewhat generic. It should work for any XSLT without namespaces.

We are passing two parameters to XSLT, i.e. XML element name and its new value:

```
transformer.setParameter("elementToFind", "test2");
transformer.setParameter("elementValue", "Prophet");
```

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test>
   <abc value="10">data1</abc>
   <bbc value="200">data2</bbc>
   <abc value="20">
      <test2>subdata1</test2>
   </abc>
</test>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<test>
  <abc value="10">data1</abc>
  <bbc value="200">data2</bbc>
  <abc value="20">
    <test2>Prophet</test2>
  </abc>
</test>
```

**Java**

```
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.*;

public class Process3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String XSLTFILE = "e:\\Temp\\Process.xslt";
        String INFILE = "e:/Temp/Input.xml";
        String OUTFILE = "e:/Temp/Output.xml";

        try {
            // I/O
            StreamSource input = new StreamSource(new File(INFILE));
            StreamSource xslt = new StreamSource(new File(XSLTFILE));
            StreamResult output = new StreamResult(new File(OUTFILE));

            // Transformation
            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

            // XSLT parameters
            transformer.setParameter("elementToFind", "test2");
            transformer.setParameter("elementValue", "Prophet");
            transformer.transform(input, output);
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException tce) {
            tce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="elementToFind" select="'test2'"/>
    <xsl:param name="elementValue" select="'Prophet'"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()=$elementToFind]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="$elementValue"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the details you asked for. Please let me know if there is something more you want to know?

Comment: @Prophet, thanks for the OP modifications. Please try my answer. It should work for your XML. You would need to change a couple of things in the Java code: (1) Paths to 3 files, (2) Two parameter values for XSLT.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow, thanks! Upvote for now anyway :)

Comment: @Prophet. Good deal. Tomorrow is another day.

Comment: It's strange, but simply removing the `indent="yes"` worked fine! So, I definitely prefer Michael's solution. But, again, thanks a lot!